# How to implement std::when_any without polling?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, standards, c++17

Consider http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/when_any. The following is just a **naive** and **simplified** implementation:

```
#include <future>

template<typename Iterator>
auto when_any(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (auto pos = first; pos != last; ++pos)
        {
            if (pos->is_ready())
            {
                return std::move(*pos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not satisfied because it is a busy polling in an infinite loop.

**Is there a way to avoid busy polling?**

Comment: That's not what `when_any()` does.

Comment: This is more of a [`wait_for_any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.wait_for_any) than [`when_any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.when_any).

Comment: That's just a naive and simplified version. The key issue is how to avoid polling.

Comment: Define what is polling for you. I see no relation with [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, busy polling means the thread executing `when_any` will keep busy, rather than entering a waiting state and being notified when any future is ready.

Comment: It may be worth looking at condition variables.

Comment: @Galik how are condition variables​ going to help here?

Comment: @yurikilochek Condition variables avoid polling by sleeping until they receive a signal.

Comment: @Galik I am aware. I don't see how you would use them here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A polling free version would launch 1 thread per future and have them set a condition variable with which future is ready.

Then you "leak" the threads until the futures are ready while returning the fact one is ready.

This sucks.  But no polling.

To do better, you need to have a future with a continuation you can set (and remove ideally).  Then you just ask the futures to notify you when done, then wait .  This requires modifying or writing your own future.

This is one of the reasons both continuations and `when_any` are both proposed for standarization.  You need them in the future.

Now if you have your own system, you can base it off a thread safe queue delivering stuff rather than futures, implemented via condition variables.  This requires cooperation at the point of "future" creation.

```
struct many_waiter_t {
  std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::vector<std::size_t> index;

  std::size_t wait() {
    auto l = lock();
    cv.wait(l, [this]{
      return !index.empty();
    });
    auto r = index.back();
    index.pop_back();
    return r;
  }
  void set( std::size_t N ) {
    {
      auto l = lock();
      index.push_back(N);
    }
    cv.notify_one();
  }
};
template<class T>
std::future<T> add_waiter( std::future<T> f, std::size_t i, std::shared_ptr<many_waiter_t> waiter )
{
  return std::async([f = std::move(f), waiter, i]{
    auto r = f.get();
    waiter.set(i);
    return r;
  });
}
```

Consuming an array of futures `fs`, we can generate a new array of futures `f2s` and a waiter, such that the waiter can be non-spinlock waited against until a future is ready, and the `f2s` correspond to the original `fs`.

You can repeatedly wait on the `waiter` until the `f2s` are all ready.

Comment: How are you going to recover futures other than the ready one when you have threads blocked on them?

Comment: @yurikilochek Those threads produce futures in turn that are made ready when the future they are waiting on is made ready.  In effect, you are wrapping `future<foo>` in a `future<foo>` that *also* triggers a (shared) condition variable before itself becomes ready.

Comment: @Okay, that would work, but a typical use case of processing result, removing ready future from the set, and waiting on the rest, in a loop, would spawn insane amounts of threads.

Comment: @yuri I said it sucked.  You can do a but better with a singleton if you can distinguish future by its state.

Comment: @yuri you can avoid that if you can distinguish your futures from other ones, and know you know when they finish.  Ie operate on shared ptr shared future, and return same.

Comment: @yurikilochek Toy implementation added.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, futures without continuations are of very limited usefulness.

If you are forced to do this and to use `std::future`, I suggest smarter polling via [`.wait_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) with [increasing timeouts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff).

Answer (score 2):

[I have posted an implementation of `when_any` over on CodeReview.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176168/non-polling-implementation-of-stdwhen-any) As Yakk said in his answer,

> To do better, you need to have a future with a continuation you can set (and remove ideally). Then you just ask the futures to notify you when done, then `wait`. This requires modifying or writing your own future.

So my implementation relies on `future::then()`, and the gist of it is:

```
template<class... Futures>
struct when_any_shared_state {
    promise<tuple<Futures...>> m_promise;
    tuple<Futures...> m_tuple;
    std::atomic<bool> m_done;
    std::atomic<bool> m_count_to_two;

    when_any_shared_state(promise<tuple<Futures...>> p) :
        m_promise(std::move(p)), m_done(false), m_count_to_two(false) {}
};

template<class... Futures>
auto when_any(Futures... futures) -> future<tuple<Futures...>>
{
    using shared_state = detail::when_any_shared_state<Futures...>;
    using R = tuple<Futures...>;
    promise<R> p;
    future<R> result = p.get_future();

    auto sptr = make_shared<shared_state>(std::move(p));
    auto satisfy_combined_promise =
        [sptr](auto f) {
            if (sptr->m_done.exchange(true) == false) {
                if (sptr->m_count_to_two.exchange(true)) {
                    sptr->m_promise.set_value(std::move(sptr->m_tuple));
                }
            }
            return f.get();
        };
    sptr->m_tuple = tuple<Futures...>(futures.then(satisfy_combined_promise)...);
    if (sptr->m_count_to_two.exchange(true)) {
        sptr->m_promise.set_value(std::move(sptr->m_tuple));
    }
    return result;
}
```

You attach a continuation to each incoming `future` (using `then`). This continuation holds a `shared_ptr` to a shared state. The shared state holds a count-to-one (`m_done`) and a count-to-two (`m_count_to_two`). Each continuation that executes will increment the count-to-one; if it's the winner, it will also increment the count-to-two. The main thread will also increment the count-to-two after it finishes setting up all this stuff. As soon as the count-to-two has reached 2 (indicating that the main thread finished setting up *and* at least one continuation has executed), we'll call `set_value` on the promise corresponding to `when_any`'s return future. Ta-da!

Comment: Sometimes the answer to a C++ question is just "ask Arthur" :) Nice solution.